# Detecting if user has entered date, time or datetime

Tags: javascript, momentjs, datetime-format

I have an input field in which users can either enter the following:

```
Datetime: DD-MMM-YY HH:mm:ss.SSS
Date:     DD-MMM-YY
Time:     HH:mm:ss
```

I am trying to determine which of the above 3 a user has entered, for example:

```
var timeInput = $scope.userDatetime;
var timeOnly = moment(timeInput, "HH:mm:ss").isValid();
```

The above can tell me if a user has entered a time only, but can i determine if they have entered a date only or date and time?

Additionally, looking at the moment docs, i can see the above can be modified to:

```
var timeOnly = moment(timeInput, "HH:mm:ss", true).isValid();
```

Comment: if it's gotta be one of those 3, just check the length of the input.

Answer (score 0):

Since your input can have different formats, you can use [moment parsing with multiple formats](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-formats/). As the docs says:

> If you don't know the exact format of an input string, but know it could be one of many, you can use an array of formats.
>
> This is the same as [String + Format](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/), only it will try to match the input to multiple formats.
>
> Moment uses some simple heuristics to determine which format to use. In order:
>
> - Prefer formats resulting in valid dates over invalid ones.
> - Prefer formats that parse more of the string than less and use more of the format than less, i.e. prefer stricter parsing.
> - Prefer formats earlier in the array than later

Moreover you can use [`creationData()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/creation-data/) to get the format used.

Here a simple example of use:

```js
function getFormatInserted(value){
  var mom = moment(value, ["HH:mm:ss", 'DD-MMM-YY HH:mm:ss.SSS', 'DD-MMM-YY'], true);
  if( mom.isValid() ){
    return mom.creationData().format;
  }
  return '';
}

$('#btn').click(function(){
  var value = $('#date').val();
  var format = getFormatInserted(value);
  $('#result').html(format);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="date">
<button type="button" id="btn">Get format</button>
<span id="result"></span>
```