# Function to get the input provided to momentjs

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Is there any function to get the input that was provided to moment()

In the example below, inputDate becomes null.

```
var date = moment("invalid date");
if(!data.isValid()){
  return { message: "Invalid date", inputDate: date }
}
```

I can access the input using internals i.e. `date._i` but was wondering if there's any function that would return the input provided to moment constructor.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`creationData()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/creation-data/)

> After a moment object is created, all of the inputs can be accessed with `creationData()` method:
>
> ```
> moment("2013-01-02", "YYYY-MM-DD", true).creationData() === {
>     input: "2013-01-02",
>     format: "YYYY-MM-DD",
>     locale: Locale obj,
>     isUTC: false,
>     strict: true
> }
> ```

Here a live example:

```js
var date = moment("invalid date", moment.ISO_8601);
console.log(date.creationData().input);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.19.4/moment.min.js"></script>
```

As a side note:

- I've used [`moment.ISO_8601`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/special-formats/) in my snippet to prevent *Deprecation Warning*, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43101278/4131048).
- Something quite similar was asked (but not a duplicate) was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42024241/4131048).